# Url connection Inputstream and outputstream objects

Tags: java, url, inputstream, outputstream

This is my code

```
URL url = new URL("http://172.16.32.160:8080/epramaan/loginotp");
URLConnection connection1 = url.openConnection();
connection1.setDoOutput(true);

ObjectOutputStream out=new ObjectOutputStream(connection1.getOutputStream());
out.writeObject(send);
out.flush();
out.close();

ObjectInputStream in = new ObjectInputStream(connection1.getInputStream());
String output=(String)in.readObject();
in.close();

//Rest of the code
```

Once the OutputStream writes data to the stream, will the object InputStream stop execution till the response is received?

Comment: You should open the input Stream before sending any data to ensure you'll get everything you need from the server

Comment: You mean before sending data using out.writeObject() I should initialise object inputStream? Can you please elaborate

Comment: @MichaelLaffargue - Actually, I don't think that is necessary.  The HTTP 1.1 RFC says this - *"After receiving and interpreting a request message, a server responds with an HTTP response message."*.  (Section 6).  The operative word is "after".  A server that started sending a response while still reading the request would be in violation of the spec.  Therefore, there's no need to open the input stream until the output stream has been closed.

Comment: @StephenC You may be right for HTTP exchanges but I think it's good practice to prepare yourself to receive data before launching the whole write/read process.

Comment: @MichaelLaffargue: Do you mean that we should initialize the input stream object before sending any data? Because some times I seem to be getting java.io.StreamCorruptedException when using multiple input and output object streams(only string are sent). So will opening the input stream before sending any data help?

Comment: @user1139023 - no it won't help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume that by *stop execution* you mean block.

Just noticed that you are using readObject and not read. Please elaborate what kind of data you are reading/writing and why are u using object streams ?

As you mentioned you are using String, I would suggest to use method `readFully(byte[] buf)`. This method blocks till all the bytes are read. Once you have the byte array, a [String can be created](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#String%28byte%5B%5D%29) from this byte array.

Comment: The question is using readObject(), not read(). The API of readObject() does not specify blocking

Comment: @Santosh : I am using String data

Comment: @Santosh: What about readObject() method? Does that also block until the whole object is read. Because I seem to be getting(sometimes) java.io.StreamCorruptedException when using multiple input and output object streams.

Comment: @user1139023, when you read a java object using `ObjectInputstream`, it follows a native protocol specific to java objects. It expects certain things in certain format and order. What you are doing is reading from an URL which has totally different protocol i.e. HTTP. The native Java Object stream is not able to understand it and hence you get `java.io.StreamCorruptedException`.

Comment: @Santosh: Then why don't I get the StreamCorruptedException everytime. Can you please give a detailed answer in the answer section, so that it will be easy to accept or uptvote your answer.

Comment: @Santosh: HTTP is the transport layer and has nothing to do with the binary content. Over the HTTP protocol you get text (HTML) and binary content such as images, pdf files etc. The client performing the request knows how to read the data in the response, usually this is defined in the Content-Type header.

Comment: @OdedPeer, I got that Thanks for point it out. what I meant is in some cases (as happening here infrequently), some data is lost in transit and hence `readObject()` is not able to reconstruct the object back. For contents like PDF/images, in case of data loss, those will still be rendered by browsers although with some errors.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [InputStream.read(byte[])](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/io/InputStream.html#read%28byte%5b%5d%29) for reading the entire byte array to memory (you can get the array length from the HTTP Content-Length header) and use [URLConnection.setReadTimeout()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/net/URLConnection.html#setReadTimeout%28int%29) for timing out if you are blocking for too long.
From the byte array you can construct your object, constructing your *ObjectInputStream* over a *ByteArrayInputStream*

Comment: Why am I getting the java.io.CorruptedStreamException when using multiple Input Output Object Stream? I have closed all the object InputStream and Object Output Stream then and there.This error doesnt occur always.It occurs only for the first time I click on the Button.(The Button's onClickListener contains code for sending and Receiving)

Comment: What do you mean by "multiple Input Output Object Stream"? I don't see multiple instances in the code in your question.

Answer (score 1):

> Once the OutputStream writes data to the stream, will the object InputStream stop execution till the response is received?

Not precisely.  Opening the `InputStream` doesn't block anything, and doesn't even *cause* the request headers to be sent.  However, reading from the `InputStream` will do both of those things.

I suspect that the real cause of your problems is that you are getting an error response from the server that is something other than a serialized object; e.g. it could be a generic HTML error page from the server.  Naturally, attempting to deserialize this fails.

The correct procedure is:

1. Create the URLConnection object.
2. Set any request headers you need to.
3. Connect it (or skip this ... it will happen implicitly).
4. Open and write to the OutputStream.
5. Close the OutputStream.
6. Use `getResponseCode()` to see if the request succeeded or failed.

   1. If it succeeded, call getInputStream() and read and process the response.
   2. If it failed, call getErrorStream() and process the error output.

Comment: I have the same problem as that of "user1166690".So I ask the question he has asked "Oded peer". Why am I getting the java.io.CorruptedStreamException when using multiple Input Output Object Stream? I have closed all the object InputStream and Object Output Stream then and there.This error doesnt occur always.It occurs only for the first time I click on the Button.(The Button's onClickListener contains code for sending and Receiving)